# JMX remote connection parameters

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

I'm browsing through JMX javadocs and I stumbled on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnector.html#connect%28java.util.Map%29.

Does anyone know, what kind of parameters I can put into Map argument of connect method? I would like to know how can I change default behaviour of connection via this property map. What I'm looking into possibilities how to create JMX connection pools, or (if possible) to create single 'keep-alive' connection and re-use it for calling various mbeans.

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

There are these publicly available, documented keys:

- `JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS`
- `JMXConnectorFactory.DEFAULT_CLASS_LOADER`
- `JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES`
- `JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_CLASS_LOADER`
- `JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_DEFAULT_PACKAGE`

There are few other used keys (eg. java.naming.corba.orb) but they are unsupported and protocol specific.